# Saving time on mysql as data

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to save date and time on my mysql database and then want to show them in my webpage's comment box. But writing the following code,  my database saving time as 00:00:00 at 00:00 and in the comment box, showing as usually same thing.

```
protected function commenting_date_time(){
     $timestamp=time();
     return strftime("%m/ %d/ %y at %H:%M %p", $timestamp);
 }

public function create_comment(){

    global $database;

        $author=$_POST["author"];
    $created= $this-> Commenting_date_time();
    $bidy= $_POST["bidy"];

    $query= "INSERT INTO comment (";
    $query.=" author, created, bidy ";
    $query.=" ) VALUES ( ";
    $query.=" '{$author}', '{$created}', '{$bidy}'";
    $query.= " )";
    $insert_query=mysqli_query($database-> connection, $query);
    $database-> ensure($insert_query);
    return $insert_query;
}
```

Comment: I have been facing problems from the begging here. What the problems ? I am doing question as usually other  peoples doing, But whats wrong.

Comment: The code you provided works so the problem must be somewhere else. One thing to notice though is your method name is is all lower case `commenting_date_time()` but you call it with a capital `$this-> Commenting_date_time()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `created` column is typed as a `DATETIME`, you need to insert data into it using MySQL's date and time format (`YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`), not the display format you're using in `commenting_date_time()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It has worked according to your way. But before that I noticed that, In the bracket there is a string "at", which was disturbing, when I have removed that from there, it has worked. But couldn't be able to display the "at".

Answer (score 0):

First of all: $created= $this-> Commenting_date_time(); seems wrong, your method is named commenting_date_time() (lowercase).

And mysql knows the "NOW()" keyword [MYSQL NOW()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp), this way the database sets the current datetime.